# Apache mod_rewrite Rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

If I had the following rules:

```
Rewrite 301 /page/22 http://newdomain.com/
Rewrite 301 /page/23 http://newdomain.com/test
Rewrite 301 /page/24 http://newdomain.com/test2
Rewrite 301 / http://newdomain.com
```

Will the rules at the top take precedence over the rule I have at the bottom?
And will using:

```
Rewrite 301 / http://newdomain.com
```

Redirect ALL requests that aren't captured by the other rules to the new domain?
Or will it only work if the URL has the domainName.com with a slash following it?

And also do I need to escape a question mark in the rule, for example:

```
Redirect 301 /items/item/94?Test123 http://newdomain.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will the rules at the top take precedence over the rule I have at the bottom? And will using:

The order of the rules matter, as the rules get applied in the order that they appear. Though, `Rewrite` isn't a valid apache directive. There's `Redirect`, which is part of mod_alias, and `RewriteRule` which is part of mod_rewrite.

> `Rewrite 301 / http://newdomain.com`

Assuming you actually meant `Redirect` here, this will redirect *all* requests that didn't get caught by a previous rule. This is because `Redirect` links two URL paths together, so anything that comes after the `/` gets passed along to the target. You probably also want a `/` at the end of `http://newdomain.com`

> And also do I need to escape a question mark in the rule, for example:

No. The `Redirect` statement won't match against the query string, or everything after the `?` in a URL. The only way you can match against the query string is using mod_rewrite and the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable. An equivalent to what you are trying to do would be:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Test123$
RewriteRule ^items/item/94$ http://newdomain.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks bro, I respect you bro. (Said like Stan Marsh)

Comment: And yes I meant Redirect no Rewrite (damnit!)